# Django Database queries to 'default' are not allowed in SimpleTestCase

Tags: django, django-tests

I tried running the following tests and they both fail. I don't understand the error because my view does not have a model included.

**view**

```
class ClassroomGradebookView(TemplateView):
    """for choosing first gradebook"""
    template_name = "gradebook/gradebookstart.html"
```

**urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    ....
    path('gradebookstart/', views.ClassroomGradebookView.as_view(),
         name='gradebookstart'),
    ]
```

**test**

```
class ClassroomGradebookTests(SimpleTestCase):

    def test_classroomgradebook_url_name(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('gradebook:gradebookstart'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_classroomgradebook_status_code(self):
        response = self.client.get('/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

**error**

```
AssertionError: Database queries to 'default' are not allowed in SimpleTestCase subclasses. Either subclass TestCase or TransactionTestCase to ensure proper test isolation or add 'default' to gradebook.tests.ClassroomGradebookTests.databases to silence this failure.
```

The lines that triggered the error are:

```
response = self.client.get(reverse('gradebook:gradebookstart'))
response = self.client.get('/')
```

Comment: Which line is causing the problem (the error sample is not really telling much apart from the fact that a query is being made)...

Comment: Original post edited to include the lines that cause the error

Comment: I think the error message is actually quite clear: your view is hitting the DB at some point, but SimpleTestCases are not made for this use case, as stated in the error and in the doc (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/tools/#simpletestcase)

Comment: Also, I see that your view is a `TemplateView` but be careful about some Django tags that could use the DB, or some middlewares

Comment: Thank you. I agree the error was descriptive and your comment about TemplateView is very helpful.